# While starting Bluemix node-red application, get error (404)

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

When I try to start Node-red starter application in Bluemix, I get the below error:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('smarthomedemo.eu-gb.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Your application did not successfully deploy. Login to Bluemix and check the app's status on the dashboard to see what the issue is.

Comment: If you can open a command window and do "cf logs appname" then try to restart your application, that will help with troubleshooting as the deploy can be seen in the command window in case the fails to deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a problem with the Node.JS runtime that was not available for a while. Now it is back again. Could you check if you still see the problem?